# Template Membership Problems?

Tags: c++, templates

I get errors for the below code when I try to compile that tell me the following:

- 'isEmpty' : is not a member of '_Stack'
- Error while compiling class template member function 'void QueueS::enqueue(const T &)

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <stack>
  using namespace std;

  template <class T>
  class _Stack : public stack<T> {

  public:

     T pop(){
         T tmp=stack::top();
         stack::pop();
         return tmp;
     }
  };

  template <class T>
  class QueueS {
  public:
      QueueS(){}

     bool isEmpty() const{

     }


     void enqueue(const T& el){

      while (!output.isEmpty()) {
           input.push(ouput.pop());
      }

      input.push(el);

      }

   private:

   _Stack<T> input;
   _Stack<T> output;

  };
  ```

I'm not sure what's going on. Can anyone offer any assistance? I have obviously not implemented isEmpty yet. Was wondering if that should have an effect.

Comment: One problem is that `'isEmpty' : is not a member of '_Stack'`. This is nothing to do with templates.

Comment: What do you think `stack::top()` returns? `top` is a member function and it should be called off an *instance* of `std::stack`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but still: You shouldn't use identifiers that start with underscore and uppercase letter (such as `_Stack`). See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for a related SO post.

Comment: Better indentation would help to see that `isEmpty` is clearly defined outside the `_Stack` template.

Comment: Sorry; the indentation is clearer in my own code, but I always run into difficulty trying to paste something in the given code brackets here.

Comment: Would have tried to help if only this code was more readable, it's impossible to know what is going on...

Comment: I'll try to fix it up some more. Again, my apologies.

Comment: Indentation should be better now. I see the point now about the isEmpty() usage. I should probably be using the library defined .empty instead. Still I'm confused about the latter error.

Answer (score 1):

What is it you are trying to do? 
That wont work since isEnpty is a member function of the class _stack.
You can solve the first problem by adding the function isEmpty to your _Stack class.

Like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class _Stack : public stack<T> 
{

public:

T pop(){
T tmp=stack::top();
stack::pop();
return tmp;
}
bool isEmpty() const{

return stack::empty();
}
};

template <class T>
class QueueS {


public:
QueueS(){}

bool isEmpty() const{

}


void enqueue(const T& el){

while( !output.isEmpty()) {
input.push(output.pop());
}

input.push(el);

}

 private:
 _Stack<T> input;
 _Stack<T> output;

};


int main()
 {
 _Stack<int> sk;
 sk.isEmpty();
 QueueS<int> qu;
 qu.enqueue(4);
 return 1;
 }
```

Comment: I was just trying to use it as a check. Since my stacks are private, I was going to attempt to use the function (once written) as a go between for accessing them. Since they're declared in separate classes, though, might I be better off just using the library's .empty() check?

Comment: I'd still need an instance of the object to make that change, wouldn't I? I "get use of class template requires template argument list", and I believe that's what it is saying.

Comment: I am not quite sure what do you mean, maybe if you will add your main or the line that gave you the error.

Comment: The line return std::empty() gives the error use of class template requires template argument list.

Comment: I still don't know what do you mean, I re edited the post with a main and this worked fine where is the problem?

Comment: Verified your solution! My compiler was stuck on some garbage I had introduced in a previous solution. All good, thanks!